# How to import Data into Scikit-learn for Knn classification algorithm

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I would like to create a supervised machine learning algorithm using Knn classifier for human fall detector (Using accelerometer (X,Y,Z) Data).I have been following the Iris Dataset example but im running some issues on how to import my data.

```
SVM* = SQRT(x^2+y^2+z^2)
```

Assuming i have the data in this form ...

```
SVM                        Movement 

1.0297572529484802,        Fall
0.9845303448853164,        Fall
0.9318798205777395,        Fall
1.067801479676817,         Fall
1.0293687385966217         TDL
1.0293687385966217         TDL
1.0013990213696038         TDl
```

Comment: what is the issue

Comment: What is the issue? What is your question?

Comment: @J.Doe  My question is how should i proceed to import the data .Should i import a CSV file or .text file because the Iris dataset example `iris = datasets.load_iris()` is confusing me

Comment: you can import both excel (csv xlsx) and text file. Load your data with `pandas read` and separate your target from your features !

Comment: @J.Doe thanks. `import pandas as pd`